# Get posts done today but at least 20 minutes older

Tags: mysql

I want to get the posts from today that I made, all of them, except the ones that I posted in the last 20 minutes.

for example, now is 3:30.

I want to get all posts that I did today until 3:10.

I tried:

```
SELECT id, titulo
FROM posts
WHERE data > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

but no success. what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is set to get posts from the last 20 minutes, if you want today except the last 20 minutes, you should use `data < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 20 
MINUTE )` and not bigger than.

The second part (from today) can be done with [curdate()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function:

```
CURDATE() = DATE(data)
```

and together:

```
SELECT id, titulo
FROM posts WHERE 
data < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 20 MINUTE ) 
AND
CURDATE() = DATE(data)
ORDER BY RAND( )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is doing it the wrong way: you want to return posts older than the date it was 20 minutes ago:

```
SELECT id, titulo
FROM posts
WHERE data < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

You also said you want only today's posts, so a second test must be added. The query is then:

```
SELECT id, titulo
FROM posts
WHERE data < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
     AND DATE(data) = CURDATE()
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Documentation:
- [CURDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your queries still being fast by using indexes you need to avoid using functions on columns with potencial indexes. You can do it like this

```
WHERE data between curdate() and now() - interval 20 MINUTE
```