# use datetime instead of mysql now()?

Tags: php

I have this query:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("

SELECT id, titulo
FROM posts WHERE 
data < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 140 MINUTE ) 
AND
CURDATE() = DATE(data)
ORDER BY RAND( ) limit 1

");
 $stmt->execute();
```

instead of now() I want to use the PHP datetime, any ideas how can I use this?

Comment: Sure, you could bind the date parameter like any other, but I strongly suggest not doing this.  By having date/time done on your database servers, it's easier to ensure your time is always in sync.  In theory, the clocks on your PHP server and your MySQL server should be identical anyway.  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @FirstOne Not just possible... very likely.  :-)  $2 says this comes down to a date formatting issue.  But, giving the benefit of the doubt for now.

Comment: Why? What actual issue are you attempting to resolve here?

Comment: the problem is php date is not the same as mysql. When I recorded it I used the PHP date and to select I'm using the mysql.

Comment: I have 20.000+ rows, so I can't change it now

Comment: You could correct your data for the difference between PHP and MySQL. Ideally they should be the same. Try always to work in UTC (internally). It makes more sense to use DateTime in PHP and to use NOW() in MySQL.

Comment: @RickJoe You should output PHP's `date_default_timezone_get()` value and `SELECT @@system_time_zone` in MySQL and make sure they're the same.

Comment: php - America/Chicago and mysql - BRT

Comment: @RickJoe So, basically, your application has two different timezones. You should set the two up to use one shared timezone.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424628/get-posts-done-today-but-at-least-20-minutes-older)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can inject PHP variables into SQL statements as *bound parameters*:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
  SELECT id, titulo
  FROM posts WHERE 
  data < DATE_SUB( ? , INTERVAL 140 MINUTE ) 
  AND DATE(data) = DATE(?)
  ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 1");
$curdatetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $curdatetime, $curdatetime);
$stmt->execute();
```